# FragmentManager replace not working?

Tags: android, fragment

I am having a hard time figuring out why my FragmentManager isn't working.
I'm using an Android studio template for nav drawer activity. The most confusing thing is, I have the exact same code in another app and it works just fine.

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.nav_camera:
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            Log.i("ID", String.valueOf(id));

            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:
            break;
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_main, fragment)
            .commit();

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;

}
```

Now, when I click on the nav_camera it logs the click just fine, but nothing else happens, the fragment doesn't get replaced. No errors, no exceptions, just the same screen over and over.

Fragment code, nothing here just testing:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
}
}
```

Fragment layout, just a blank:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

The rest of the code is auto generated by andorid studio.

Here is content_main, which I am trying to replace with fm:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.goran.mymoviedb.movies.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

It should replace the layout with a blank one whan nav_camera is clicked but nothing happens, even though correct click is registered.

Comment: Your code is not complete, however I will try. Each activity is entitled to one java code for dynamic content and one XML layout for static code. The activity can have zero to many fragments. each fragment is entitled to one java and one XML. This code you posted should be in the activity. Your problem appears to be you directly extend listfragment rather than extending it See Mylistfragment here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_fragment.htm

Comment: Ofcourse it's in the activity, i wrote that it was auto generated nav bar activty. Nothing is changed except the method I posted.

Comment: What I am saying is you made an MainActivity extends Activity and you should have MyFragment extends ListFragment.

Comment: @Pomagranite that's not accurate what you're saying , post your answer if you have the solution and OP will try the full code and accept if you're right otherwise don't mislead people

Comment: @GoranKovač please, try the solution i offered it should  work

Comment: ListFragment is a reserved word and User created class. Just like I create a class called "if" or a class called "Activity" or a class called "View" it confuses things

Comment: Yes, it confused him. ListFragment is my custom Fragment class, not ListFragment from Android. I renamed it to MyFragment but it doesn't help the situation

Comment: are you importing   android.app.ListFragment or something from your package.ListFragment ?

Comment: My package, it's not android.app.ListFragment, just custom class that extends Fragment

Comment: the "replace" swaps one fragment id for another fragment id in your case you attempt to "replace" layout id with fragment id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code is working but the issue is that you have `blank` layout and because background of fragment layout is by default transparent you can not see the change. Put background color on your root layout of fragment (`LinearLayout`) for example: `android:background="@android:color/white"`
and you will see fragement replacement.

Comment: Oh, that makes so much sense. I assumed it was blank/white background, feel so silly now. Thanks! :)